# Handshake SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS

Tags: tls

Can someone confirm that SSLv2, SSLv3, and TLS have the same Handshake process (ClientHello/ServerHello, ..., ClientKeyExchange ...)?

If not, can you tell me the main differences between theses three protocols?

I am asking this because, as you can see in the image below, I can see ClientMasterKey (SSLv2) instead of ClientKeyExhange(TLS1.2). 
ClientKeyExhange must contains the Premaster secret, and I have never seen ClientMasterKey in handshake process.

[image]

Comment: In TLS 1.2 there is no handshake message as ClientMasterKey if thats what you are asking.

Comment: This is, indeed, what i'm asking thanks. Have you got more informations about theses two packets (ClientMasterKey VS ClientKeyExchange) ?

Comment: You can look to the [ClientKeyExchange](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.7) message from TLS1.2 documentation. There is another document about [ssl2](http://www.homeport.org/~adam/ssl.html) which mentions ClientMasterKey Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Handshake differs greatly between SSLv2 and SSLv3**. All versions of TLS (1.0, 1.1, 1.2) use the SSLv3 format and although they add some new options and features they don't alter the basic flow relevant to DROWN. Although formatted differently, the security content of SSLv2 `ClientMasterKey` is the same as SSLv3/TLS `ClientKeyExchange` when using RSA keyexchange, in that both contain an RSA (specifically PKCS1v1.5) encryption of the only secret information needed to determine the keys, which is exactly why DROWN works.

**The critical difference is SSLv2 ServerVerify**. [Quoting from the DROWN paper:](https://drownattack.com/drown-attack-paper.pdf)

> **2.2 SSL and TLS** ... 
>   **The SSLv2 handshake protocol.** ... 
>     The server responds with a `ServerVerify` message
>   consisting of the `challenge` $r_c$ encrypted with
>   the `server_write_key`. ... 
>     Our attack exploits the fact the server always decrypts
>   an RSA-PKCS#1 v1.5 ciphertext, computes the
>   `server_write_key`, and *immediately* responds with a
>   `ServerVerify` message. The SSLv2 standard implies
>   this message ordering, but does not make it explicit. However,
>   we observed this behavior in every implementation
>   we examined.
>
> **The TLS handshake protocol**. ... or SSLv3, ... 
>   The two main details relevant to our attacks are: ... 
>   * After receiving the `ClientKeyExchange` message,
>   the server waits for the `ClientFinished` message,
>   in order to authenticate the client.

This is why SSLv2 provides the Bleichenbacher-style oracle but SSLv3 or TLS does not, so DROWN can use the SSLv2 oracle to break SSLv3 or TLS sessions.

Comment: Hi, why is it that one has to transform a RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 TLS conformant ciphertext to RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 SSLv2 conformant ciphertext before being fed to the Blechenbacher oracle?

Comment: (@freak_warrior) answered at new Q http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44634/tls-conformant-ciphertexts-and-sslv2-conformant-ciphertexts-for-blechenbacher-at/44727#44727