# TLS-conformant ciphertexts and SSLv2-conformant ciphertexts for Blechenbacher attack for DROWN attack

Tags: rsa, tls, key-exchange, attack, pkcs1

This is regarding the published paper on the DROWN attack (https://drownattack.com/drown-attack-original-report.pdf)

It was mentioned in the paper that for TLS, RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 is used to encapsulate the 48-byte premaster secret exchanged during the handshake. Does means that  a random padding string PS is prepended to the 48-byte premaster secret to this formatted massage

```
([00] || [02] || PS || [00] || pms)
```

before the actual RSA encryption is done?

If yes, I have 2 questions

**(1st question)**
How does the decryption oracle in the SSLv2 server differentiate between TLS-conformant ciphertexts and SSLv2-conformant ciphertexts, since the padded TLS plaintext also contains `([00]||[02])` as the 1st 2 bytes?

**(2nd question)** Why is it that one has to transform a RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 TLS conformant ciphertext to RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 SSLv2 conformant ciphertext before being fed to the Blechenbacher oracle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **(background)** It wasv mentioned in the paper that for TLS, RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 is used to encapsulate the 48-byte premaster secret exchanged during the handshake. Does means that a random padding string PS is prepended to the 48-byte premaster secret to this formatted massage
>   ([00] || [02] || PS || [00] || pms)
>   before the actual RSA encryption is done?

Yes, with the correction that PS is random *nonzero*. (I'm sensitive to this because I once had to interop-test with a system that didn't correctly exclude zero from PKCS1-type2 padding, resulting in several percent of cryptograms causing spurious test failures.)

> **(1st question)** How does the decryption oracle in the SSLv2 server differentiate between TLS-conformant ciphertexts and SSLv2-conformant ciphertexts, since the padded TLS plaintext also contains ([00]||[02]) as the 1st 2 bytes?

As described in 2.2, for SSLv2 the PKCS1-encrypted value is $mk_{secret}$ whose size depends on the ciphersuite selected.

As described in 3.2, the SSLv2 oracle (server) checks "$m$ starts with
`0x00 02` followed by non-null padding bytes, a delimiter
byte `0x00`, and a `master_key` $mk_{secret}$ of correct byte
length $k$" where k depends on the ciphersuite; examples given are 5 to 24.

48 is not equal to the k value for the selected SSLv2 ciphersuite, or indeed any of them.

3.3 confirms this: "But since no SSLv2 cipher suites have
48-byte key strengths, this means that a valid TLS ciphertext
is invalid to our oracle O." The rest of 3.3 explains the (clever) process used to find a mathematically-related *and* SSLv2-conformant ciphertext.

> **(2nd question)** Why is it that one has to transform a RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 TLS conformant ciphertext to RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 SSLv2 conformant ciphertext before being fed to the Blechenbacher oracle?

Because the SSLv2 oracle only gives a distinguishable response for an SSLv2-conformant ciphertext. For *all* TLS-valid ciphertexts it gives a randomized response from which no information can be extracted -- but the entire purpose of an oracle is to leak information.